# Parsing XML problem with LINQ 

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, .net-3.5, linq-to-xml

I want to get some values from the XML file and insert them into a ListBox using LINQ. Where am I wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tells> 
    <defindividual name="name1"/>
    <instanceof>
      <individual name="name1"/>
      <catom name="value"/>
    </instanceof>

    <defindividual name="name2"/>
    <instanceof>
      <individual name="name2"/>
      <catom name="value"/>
    </instanceof>

    <defindividual name="name3"/>
    <instanceof>
      <individual name="name3"/>
      <catom name="otherValue"/>
    </instanceof>
</tells>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument owlXML = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("App_Data\\myFile.xml"));

    var items = from item in owlXML.Descendants("instanceof")
                where item.Element("catom").Attribute("name").Value == "value"
                select new
                {
                    catom = item.Element("catom").Attribute("name").Value
                };

    foreach (var item in items) 
    {
        //ListBox1.DataSource = item;
        //ListBox1.DataBind();

        ListBox1.Items.Add(item.catom);
    }        
}
```

Comment: The problem is my ListBox1 is always empty. I tried to fill it with List<> items and it worked, but when I try to fill it with IEnumerable items nothing happens.

Comment: I updated my answer adding `ToArray()`. You can also use `ToList() but the resulting overhead is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var names = from item in owlXML.Descendants("instanceof")
            let name = item.Element("catom").Attribute("name")  // cache
            where name.Value == "value"
            select name;

foreach (var name in names.ToArray()) 
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add(name);
}
```

or

```
var items = from item in owlXML.Descendants("instanceof")
            let name = item.Element("catom").Attribute("name")  // cache
            where name.Value == "value"
            select new { catom = name }; // if ListBox is configured to field="catom"

ListBox1.DataSource = items.ToArray(); // items!
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: <tells uri="" xmlns="http://dl.kr.org/dig/2003/02/lang">  -  I found out that when I add this "uri" to the tells tag the LINQ query is empty. I guess something goes wrong but what and why?

Comment: @Maistora: That's namespace, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387093.aspx), especially [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943852.aspx)